# Golang ReverseProxy HTTP Timeout

Tags: go, reverse-proxy

I have a go based single host reverse proxy being used in my application. The request to the downstream service that the proxy makes gets timedout and cancelled automatically after 30 seconds.

After looking at the http package github, I found a similar issue: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/28876.

The suggested response is that the HTTP timeout needs to be set, not the TCP dialing part, but I'm not able to find the configuration to do that.

Need some help on that.

```
timeout := service.httpConfig.ProxyTimeout / 1000
proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(clusterURL)
transport := http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).Clone()
transport.ResponseHeaderTimeout = time.Duration(timeout) * time.Second

proxy.ServeHTTP(c.Writer, c.Request)
```

Doing this didn't help. The request always throws a 504 after 30 seconds even if my ProxyTimeout is 180,000.

Answer (score 0):

try to replace Transport, like this

```
proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(clusterURL)

proxy.Transport = &http.Transport{
    Proxy: http.ProxyFromEnvironment,
    Dial: (&net.Dialer{
        Timeout:   180 * time.Second,
        KeepAlive: 180 * time.Second,
    }).DialContext,
    TLSHandshakeTimeout: 180 * time.Second,
}

proxy.ServeHTTP(c.Writer, c.Request)
```

and check timeout on *http.Server

```
httpServer := &http.Server{
  ReadTimeout:  180 * time.Second,
  WriteTimeout: 180 * time.Second,
}
```